# Magento2.1.3 Deploy Version error

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I am using Magento latest version Magneto2.1.3 when I run this command and check **admin/frontend** I face Js missing issue in console..

Command Run :: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Issue ::

> Js missing whole pages.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have just face this issue.

This issue has **been raised due to mod_rewrite**.

If you goes to `pub/static/.htaccess`.   at  there in [*.htacess*](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/pub/static/.htaccess#L16)  have some rewrite rules for ***Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache*** from static content. That ***is not  working  that what why in static content  urls*** is look like

```
www.example.com/pub/static/version[Version].....
```

**See at**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
</IfModule>
```

### Solution

May be in your `mod_rewrite` does `not enable properly`.You  should enable it  properly in order to resolve  your problem.

Comment: You should enable it properly in order to resolve your problem..'- HOW??

Comment: What is your have use?

Comment: can you share your .htaccess working file?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/538212 please check this url

Comment: @AmitBera i am having same issue frontend is working properly but backend gives me 404 error for js files, I tried  your solution but no luck

Comment: @AmitBera : Hi.. Can you plz check this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160707/cannot-read-property-section-loadurl-of-undefined

Comment: sorry.. dude.. i donot have enough idea for this issue

Comment: Yo @AmitBera - I'm facing this with NGINX. Do you know is there a solution to tell the browser this info with NGINX?