# cannot read property 'section loadurl' of undefined

Tags: customer, header, magento-2.1.3

I'm getting this error on the firebug while loading homepage. Due to this error the pages are not loading fully. only the Header, Nav Menu and Footer and showing. The main content sections are not showing.

Tried a lot to debug the error but not successful. Any help ??

[image]

Google Chrome console error

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried `static-content deploy`

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala :  Yes... But didn't worked

Comment: please let me know which command Have you used for deploy, give full command.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya : Hi I used this command

 C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.30> php C:\wamp\www\magento\bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy

and the result was
*Successful: 2217 files; errors: 0*

Comment: please run command, C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.30> php C:\wamp\www\magento\bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB let me know after run this command.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya : I have updated my frontend locale into en_US and tried the static deploy command. Didn't worked. I also have updated the error image in the question. plz have a look.

Comment: deploy command is not working? remove var folder and try again.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya: no no.. I mean the issue is still there even after the deploy command.. Deploy command worked well and got the result "successful"

Comment: rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs/

after this command run 

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: your _requirejs is not updated new js file so remove _requirejs folder and run again command.

Comment: @Magento2Devloper: I tried that now.. I have deleted pub/static/_requirejs folder and fontend folder.. then i ran the static deploy command.. Still homepage is broken and that error is showing... is there any issue in customer-data.js file??

Comment: may be the issue regarding deploy version file..check in error version_14xxx and your deploy in version file name different..so issue generate.

Comment: @Magento2Devloper: Yes the version shown in the firebug links is *1487574274* But the version of deployed files after the command is *1487576729*..

What should i do now to load the correct version? :(

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155303/magento2-1-3-deploy-version-error...may be work for you..

Comment: Refer this article. =>http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94502/magento2-re-generate-css-file-in-pub-static-folder

Comment: @Magento2Devloper : Hi Now my files are loading with correct deployed version.. But however the issue is still present. I think it is related to customer-data.js file exception

Comment: @Anjana have your issue is fixed. i am also stucked in same problem. any idea or help will appreciated

Answer (score 7):

The data that code references (`sectionLoadUrl`) is usually set in the following snippet that (should) be on every Magento front-end page

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{"*":{"Magento_Customer\/js\/customer-data":{"sectionLoadUrl":"http:\/\/magento-2-1-4.dev\/customer\/section\/load\/","cookieLifeTime":"3600","updateSessionUrl":"http:\/\/magento-2-1-4.dev\/customer\/account\/updateSession\/"}}}    
</script>
```

So, either something in your system removed this snippet, *or* you're somehow invoking the functionality in `Magento_Customer/js/customer-data` before the snippet's had a chance to run.

Comment: M using this in footer.phtml file require([
                'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
            ], function (customerData) {
                var sections = ['cart'];
                customerData.invalidate(sections);
                customerData.reload(sections, true);
            });
And getting error as above.
How to solve this?

Comment: @Magecode You should probably post that as a new question with more more details, and not as a comment.

Comment: It's possible that this is an example of this issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/12314

Comment: @Magecode could you fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by adding following code to `<Magento_directry>/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
  <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block name="customer.section.config" class="Magento\Customer\Block\SectionConfig"
               template="Magento_Customer::js/section-config.phtml"/>
        <block name="customer.customer.data"
               class="Magento\Customer\Block\CustomerData"
               template="Magento_Customer::js/customer-data.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your custom Module model files If you have installed some. There must be some typo error. I have faced the same problem and for me, it works as I have mistaken in Namespace path and due to that typo error it was generating same js error on all pages if not then remove module-customer from pub and try deploy theme again

Comment: Hi I have updated my question with a new image from chrome console. It shows sectionLoadUrl is undefined in options.sectionLoadUrl in Magento/Customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js..

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: I dont have any custom Module model files.. Anyhow i have double checked the namespaces of my custom Module Block files. This was working fine till morning. I was doing some style changes in my cms pages and footer. :( after that this error is showing while accessing home,login,register pages. CMS pages are fine.

Comment: can you please explain the changes you have done in CMS page ?

Comment: Can you please send me the complete right side of chrome screenshot which you have attached. i cannot see the URL where it's generating error in pub file

Comment: I have updated the chrome error image. the error is occurring in customer-data.js file. The changes I have made so far are 1) created custom theme with custom header, navigation menu, custom store switcher in header,custom footer. that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it removing the `default.xml` from my theme `Magento_Customer`.

```
app/design/frontend/Theme/Name/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml
```

I think this custom module is loading before the snipped and the `url` for `ajax` call is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this using window on load:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
require([
        'jquery'
    ],
    function($) {
        $(window).on("load", function() {
            require([
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
                'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry'
            ], function(defaultTotal, customerData, quote, defaultProcessor, customerAddressProcessor, rateRegistry) {
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    /** Do your code here */
                });

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It is calling twice and when i click any additional fee button it is submitting twice.

Answer (score 0):

In our case this was a bit of code in a default template which was loading the customer-data.js file after it had already been called on the success page.

We found file: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml`

was loading this code:

```
<script>
    require([
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    ], function (customerData) {
        var sections = ['cart'];
        customerData.invalidate(sections);
        customerData.reload(sections, true);
    });
</script>
```

Removing this code fixed it, which we did by creating a copy of this file in our theme templates directory and removing the offending code snippet.

You can use Chrome Dev tools to find out where the error was happening and then just before in that file on your local dev add in a `console.trace();` call to establish what was calling the function which is throwing the error in the console. Follow the chain to where you are loading things improperly.

Answer (score 0):

I had previously removed **"content"** container from **theme.xml,**
I fixed it by adding following code to the **theme.xml**:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block name="customer.section.config" class="Magento\Customer\Block\SectionConfig"
           template="Magento_Customer::js/section-config.phtml"/>
    <block name="customer.customer.data"
           class="Magento\Customer\Block\CustomerData"
           template="Magento_Customer::js/customer-data.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed content block which caused this error:

```
<referenceBlock name="content" display="false"/>
```

You can better hide it with css and not remove it in your xml

```
  .cms-index-index {
    .column.main {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had removed the 'main' container in a template.