# cannot read property 'section loadurl' of undefined in customer-data.js:89 Magento2

Tags: magento2

**i have already try all the given solutions but its not woking for me.
**

[image]

Comment: i had use all the solution is given on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160707/cannot-read-property-section-loadurl-of-undefined.

but its not work for me

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue when calling `.reload` in `jQuery(window).load`
e.g.

```
require('Magento_Customer/js/customer-data').reload();
```

Changing it to the following fixed the issue:

```
require(['Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function(customerData) {
    customerData.reload();
});
```

It seems the first block runs before the customer-data is fully loaded.

Comment: how we can use this??
Error occur when we override - get-total.js

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
require([
        'jquery'
    ],
    function($) {
        $(window).on("load", function() {
            require([
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
                'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry'
            ], function(defaultTotal, customerData, quote, defaultProcessor, customerAddressProcessor, rateRegistry) {
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    /** Do your code here */
                });

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```