# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sectionLoadUrl' of undefined

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript

I am newbie in Web Development. I am working on a Magento ver. 2.1.6. I am getting this error on my every page after loading the page.

[image].

How can I solve this error. any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

**NOTE:** This question may be duplicate to [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160707/cannot-read-property-section-loadurl-of-undefined). But this does not helped me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all module files in vendor=>magento and delete all the things in pub=>static folder and setup:upgrade,indexer:reindex make sure before delete backup your system

Comment: Thanks for your answer but not working

Comment: check your permissions