# Magento 2.2.7 - Reload totals cart using Ajax

Tags: ajax, totals, magento2.2.7

I have tried below code

```
        var deferred = $.Deferred();  
        getTotalsAction([], deferred);
```

But no luck and instead below error i am facing

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sectionLoadUrl' of undefined

Same code is working in Magento 2.1.9 but not working in Magento 2.2.7

Could you guys please help me out. 
How to Refresh/Reload the totals cart via ajax
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code in ajax done function:

```
   require(
                    [
                        'jquery',
                        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
                        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
                    ],
                    function ($, getTotalsAction, customerData) {
                        var sections = ['cart'];
                        customerData.reload(sections, true);
                        // The totals summary block reloading
                        var deferred = $.Deferred();
                        getTotalsAction([], deferred);
                      }
                    );
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but the code is not working in magento 2.2.7

Comment: This is working on 2.2.7 . Can you please share your full code?

Comment: require(['jquery','uiComponent','Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote','ko','Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals','Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader','Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals','Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function($,Component,quote,ko , getTotalsAction,fullScreenLoader,totals,customerData) {
$.ajax({
async:true,
beforeSend: function() {   
},success: function(data) {
var deferred = $.Deferred();  
var sections = ['cart'];
customerData.reload(sections, true);
fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();                          
getTotalsAction([], deferred); 
}
});
});

Comment: i have aded the code above please check and let me know please.

Comment: Try these solutions :
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160707/cannot-read-property-section-loadurl-of-undefined

Comment: and is there any other solutions.